# Can you see a photon from the side?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, photons

I'm trying to understand the shape and size of individual quantum particles.

According to the book [Tales of the Quantum](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Tales_of_the_Quantum.html?id=mGduDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) the quantum wave of a photon in the visible range is a few centimetres wide. The Very large telescope in Chile showed that infrared photons are 100 metres wide and radio photons are 36km wide. But De Broglie said that an individual quantum fills all of space.

So my question is, if two people have their heads pressed against each other and are looking at a distant star, are they looking at the same photon or different photons?  Is the answer different if they are 1 metre, or 1km or 10,000km apart? And is the answer different if they are looking at infrared or radio waves?

To put the question a different way, if we shoot a stream photons in a straight direction, can I see them if I look at them from the side if I am just 1cm, or 1 metre or 1km off to the side?

Comment: elementary particles do not have a size so I cannot venture to form an answer.  Can you provide some context to this concept, other than your pressed head example?

Comment: @ggcg In the book and referring to the 2 slit experiment, it says "Each photon is a spread out wave that passes through both slits and then fills the screen just before interacting with the scree.  Because a photon can not be subdivided it must deposit its entire energy into just one atom on the screen."   So this would imply that a particle does have a size and my question remains, if two people are looking at a star, are they looking at the same photon or different photons? Or, does the photon collapse into one person's eye and the other person is seeing a different photon?

Comment: It does not imply that at all.  A "photon" as it is described here is a spread out wave, not a particle.  The size of a wave could be infinite.  The Atom is NOT a particle in the elementary sense but a system.  The photon in the quantum sense is a state of the field.  This state cannot be subdivided.  The particle is being taken too seriously.

Comment: Are you asking if a photon, presumably distributed out in space somehow due to having a wavelength (I don't know if this is actually correct or not), can be interacted with via only a portion of it? Or whether the entire photon must be interacted with for detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classical light sources, such as stars, light bulbs and even laser don't emit single photons, but [complicated quantum states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_statistics) with amplitudes for $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$, $|2\rangle$, ... photons, even if the intensity goes to $0$. Therefore it is hard to identify a single photon from them.

You can obtain true single photons for example from the emission of a single atom. In free space an atom emits in the same spatial pattern as a [dipole antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna#Radiation_pattern_and_gain). Expanding at the speed of light in all directions the photon can extend without any fundamental limit.

Would two people at any distance be able to see the same photon? Clearly no. If the photon is detected at one location, for example one particular [rod cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rod_cell) in your left eye it localizes exactly there and can't be detected anywhere else anymore. This is the so-called [collapse of the wavefunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_problem).

To address your last question: If you collimate the photons from a single atom into a laser-like beam, like a [Gaussian beam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam) there is a small chance that you detect photons in your eye, falling off as $\propto e^{-2r^2}$ where $r$ is the distance between the beam axis and your eye.

Comment: Your comment on the collapse of the wave function makes sense. Could it have collapsed into either person's eye if they were right next to each other? And what could have been their maximum distance apart for this to occur?

Comment: @foolishmuse It can be detected at all places where the amplitude of the emission pattern is nonzero. For an atom in free space this can be everyone in line of sight, independent of their relative distance. But if the photon is distributed over a large area the chances that it is detected in a particular person's eye becomes very small.